# gravity forms Displaying a message from dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is it possible to display message/description when a user chooses an option from a dropdown menu.

Example:

if user chooses "London" from the dropdown menu then we want to display a message from the a database/file relating to "London" ideally using Ajax so not to reload the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can add a CSS Class Name to the `select` in Gravity Forms. This will make it easy for you to add an event listener via your custom Javascript/jQuery. You will need your ajax endpoint of course, but you can add a listener like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        // Set your variables here
        var select_class = 'my-select-class',
            endpoint = '/my_endpoint.php',
            notification_class = 'notification-for-select';

        var $my_select = $('.' + select_class);
        $my_select.parent().prepend('<div class="' + notification_class + '"></div>');
        $my_select.change(function (e) {
            var my_data = $my_select.val();
            $.post(endpoint, my_data, function (data) {
                $('.' + notification_class).text(data);
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```